# how to convert float to int preserving bit value

Tags: c++, hlsl, bit

I have a float4 coming into a compute shader, 3 of these floats are really floats but the fourth is 2 uints shifted together, how would i convert the float to uint by preserving the bit sequence instead of the numeric value?

on the c++ side i solved it by creating a uint pointer, filling it with the desired number and passing on the pointer as a float pointer instead. However in hlsl as similar as it is to c/c++ there are no pointers so im stuck here :|

Comment: hey @karli-raudsepp , you should go back and accept some of the answers to your questions. People worked hard answering your questions so the least you can do is show future readers which answers are most helpful.

Comment: I'm not really a C++ guy, but couldn't you cast the float into a struct of two `short`s?

Answer (score 9):

In HLSL you should be able to do the following (assuming the value you are after is in f4.w)

```
uint ui = asuint( f4.w );
uint ui1 = ui & 0xffff;
uint ui2 = ui >> 16;
```

Basically it looks like the [asuint intrinsic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is your friend :)

Comment: if an answer helps you then you should consider accepting it

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc:  I doubt he'll notice that ... I'm the one who gets notified of comments on my answer ;)

Comment: @Goz actually both the asker and the answerer will be notified about a comment on his question/answer, and of course the person who was tagged too, :)

Comment: Really? I don't get notifications when people comment on answers to my questions ...

Answer (score 2):

You could use a union.

```
float f;  // you float value is here

union X  
{  
    float f;  
    short int a[2];  
} x;  
x.f = f;

int i1 = x.a[0];  // these are your ints  
int i2 = x.a[1];
```

Comment: Hmm, a float is only 32-bits. I think you want 'short' instead of 'int'.

Comment: writing one field of an union and reading a different one is undefined behaviour in C++. The correct way would be to use memcpy

Comment: writing one field of a union and reading a different one is the whole purpose of a union, and the behavior is absolutely defined in C++.